# Grey background showing up with iOS devices on Magento product catalog sections of website

Tags: ios, magento, mobile

When you view certain pages of our magento store on iOS devices (does not show up on android or non-mobile devices), a grey background shows up behind any section of the site that is a part of the product catalog:

[image 1](http://bit.ly/NGIjyY)
[image 2](http://bit.ly/PASN4L)

The grey background also shows up behind the breadcrumbs bar, and the contact form that is native to magento, but I can't get it to display in other aspects of the site such as the main body of the home page, the body of other pages, etc.

At first I thought maybe this was a Safari iOS issue, but the error shows up in iPhone Chrome and Mercury browsers as well.

I can't get any errors to show up in iPhone's error console. I've also tried to use the iOS simulator in conjunction with iWebkit, but I'm not finding much there either.

Could this be a CSS issue? I tried to identify a similar css class for each section this is showing up in, but I can't see any similarities.

I'd be grateful for any help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your styles.css (/skin/frontend/blank/theme110/css/styles.css), just comment Line 87 which says:

`background: url("../images/main_block_bg.png") repeat scroll left top transparent;`

and let me know does it solves?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Just tried it though, and am seeing no change, issue is still showing up on iphone, after resetting safari and clearing magento cache.

Comment: Actually one sec, I think I may have commented out the wrong line.

Comment: This time I commented out line 87, and the grey error went away on the catalog portions of the site, as well as the contact form but it still shows up on the breadcrumbs bar. However, the white background that used to be behind the areas where the grey part was showing up is also gone as well. So I guess I need to figure out these questions now: 1. How do I get the white background to display on all broswers without the grey showing up on iOS broswers? 2. How do I get rid of the grey bar that is still showing up on the breadcrumbs area? OSX: http://bit.ly/SQD9Cs iPhone: http://bit.ly/OUjtsw

Comment: I knew it's not going to solve the problem completely, it was just to point you the bug. So, the problem is .png image, you need to fix that.

Comment: if you're satisfied, you can always mark the answer accepted so that other's don't waste their time. Cheers!